# Display more than one row with the same result from a field

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I need to show more than one result from each field in a table. I need to do this with only one SQL sentence, I don´t want to use a Cursor.

This seems silly, but the number of rows may vary for each item. I need this to print afterwards this information as a Crystal Report detail.

Suppose I have this table:

```
idItem     Cantidad     <more fields>
--------  -----------
    1000         3
    2000         2
    3000         5
    4000         1
```

I need this result, using one only SQL Sentence:

```
1000
1000
1000
2000
2000
3000
3000
3000
3000
3000
4000
```

where each `idItem` has `Cantidad` rows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like something that should be handled in the UI (or the report). I don't know Crystal Reports well enough to make a suggestion there. If you really, truly need to do it in SQL, then you can use a Numbers table (or something similar):

```
SELECT
    idItem
FROM
    Some_Table ST
INNER JOIN Numbers N ON
    N.number > 0 AND
    N.number <= ST.cantidad
```

You can replace the Numbers table with a subquery or function or whatever other method you want to generate a result set of numbers that is at least large enough to cover your largest cantidad.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UNPIVOT (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

- [Another example](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/unpivot.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a "numbers" table that is useful for this and many similar purposes, you can use the following SQL:

```
select t.idItem
  from myTable t
       join numbers n on n.num between 1 and t.Cantidad
order by t.idTtem
```

The numbers table should just contain all integer numbers from 0 or 1 up to a number big enough so that Cantidad never exceeds it.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need a Numbers or Tally table which is just a sequential list of integers. However, if you knew that `Cantidad` was never going to be larger than five for example, you can do something like:

```
Select idItem
From Table
    Join    (
            Select 1 As Value
            Union All Select 2
            Union All Select 3
            Union All Select 4
            Union All Select 5
            ) As Numbers
        On Numbers.Value <= Table.Cantidad
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005, you can use a CTE to do:

```
With Numbers As
    (
    Select 1 As Value
    Union All
    Select N.Value + 1
    From Numbers As N
    )
Select idItem
From Table
    Join Numbers As N
        On N.Value <= Table.Cantidad
Option (MaxRecursion 0);
```

Comment: Yes, I think of Recursion, but it is SQL 2000. My mistake not to clarify this.

Comment: @Claudi - Ok. Then either build a permanent Numbers table one time with as many integers as you need, or if the values you need is small, you can use my first solution.